# docker compose does not create network and return : "ERROR no vni provided"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, vmware-workstation

I updated my ubuntu 22.04 including docker (all of this is in a vmware workstation virtual machine).
I'm trying to run docker compose with this network parameter .

```
networks :
   gateway:
     driver: overlay
```

each time I got this :
Error response from daemon: No VNI provided .

Does anyone else have the same issue ?? How did you fix it ??

EDIT :
I did succeed to run docker compose , but I had to init a docker swarm on the computer (and specify an ipv6 address using --advertise-addr)
Then I had to add the attachable : true parameter inside the docker-compose file.

here are  the logs :

```
May 24 18:59:53 jobvm systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-8fd8d17f71538934b364ebf00981229478771efc92771b8462f56c521dde6fee\x2dinit-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 24 18:59:53 jobvm systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-8fd8d17f71538934b364ebf00981229478771efc92771b8462f56c521dde6fee-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm dockerd[6782]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:54.011252035+02:00" level=info msg="initialized VXLAN UDP port to 4789 "
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm kernel: [ 3724.339025] br0: renamed from ov-001003-i54kf
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947594.3994] manager: (vx-001003-i54kf): new Vxlan device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/89)
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm systemd-udevd[11077]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm kernel: [ 3724.426143] vxlan0: renamed from vx-001003-i54kf
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm kernel: [ 3724.465417] br0: port 1(vxlan0) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm kernel: [ 3724.465455] br0: port 1(vxlan0) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm kernel: [ 3724.485784] device vxlan0 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm kernel: [ 3724.512803] br0: port 1(vxlan0) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm kernel: [ 3724.512833] br0: port 1(vxlan0) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:54 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.136361] veth0: renamed from vethcac73c0
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm systemd-udevd[11084]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947595.1404] manager: (veth1beb0ed): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/90)
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947595.1634] manager: (vethcac73c0): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/91)
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.232621] br0: port 2(veth0) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.232668] br0: port 2(veth0) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.233558] device veth0 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.235246] br0: port 2(veth0) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.235262] br0: port 2(veth0) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.554593] br0: port 2(veth0) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.741170] eth0: renamed from veth1beb0ed
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.949681] br0: port 2(veth0) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm kernel: [ 3725.951086] br0: port 2(veth0) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:55 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 18:59:56 jobvm dockerd[6782]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:56.163088290+02:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
May 24 18:59:56 jobvm dockerd[6782]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:56.163116865+02:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
May 24 18:59:56 jobvm dockerd[6782]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:56.592933070+02:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
May 24 18:59:56 jobvm dockerd[6782]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:56.592963599+02:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm systemd-udevd[11115]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm systemd-udevd[11113]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.1857] manager: (veth5ca75b6): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/92)
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.1868] manager: (veth6019b7d): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/93)
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.1878] manager: (vethdb2d5b6): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/94)
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.1920] manager: (vethc6da593): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/95)
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.224976] veth1: renamed from veth6019b7d
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.377436] br0: port 3(veth1) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.377439] br0: port 3(veth1) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.377834] device veth1 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.378445] veth2: renamed from vethc6da593
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.4273] manager: (vethb3fa547): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/96)
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.426281] br0: port 4(veth2) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.426284] br0: port 4(veth2) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.426331] device veth2 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.426438] br0: port 4(veth2) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.426439] br0: port 4(veth2) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.427114] docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth1bcd1b7) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.427116] docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth1bcd1b7) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.427242] device veth1bcd1b7 entered promiscuous mode
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.427649] docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth1bcd1b7) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.427652] docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth1bcd1b7) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.4286] manager: (veth1bcd1b7): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/97)
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm systemd-udevd[11131]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.4357] manager: (veth4ca5297): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/98)
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.434940] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.434946] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.435087] device vethdc001de entered promiscuous mode
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.435671] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.435673] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.4375] manager: (vethdc001de): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/99)
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:59.462723059+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:59.462781160+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:59.462788985+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:59.462978897+02:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/e72abc89230a93dbd8de3bda66bf8ad91795798da5bc3b403687855a60f52593 pid=11191 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container e72abc89230a93dbd8de3bda66bf8ad91795798da5bc3b403687855a60f52593.
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:59.493194858+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:59.493247518+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:59.493273348+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T18:59:59.493414016+02:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/e7d9fa8cd2d70150e012730b41e1fbd3d4d9da9cc816f2fc0219821f46e30131 pid=11234 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-e7d9fa8cd2d70150e012730b41e1fbd3d4d9da9cc816f2fc0219821f46e30131-runc.zHc9AQ.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container e7d9fa8cd2d70150e012730b41e1fbd3d4d9da9cc816f2fc0219821f46e30131.
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm systemd-udevd[11129]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm systemd-udevd[11089]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.601012] eth0: renamed from vethdb2d5b6
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.613178] docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth1bcd1b7) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.613496] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered disabled state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.637543] eth1: renamed from veth4ca5297
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.6535] device (vethdc001de): carrier: link connected
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.652800] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethdc001de: link becomes ready
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.652890] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.652892] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.688790] eth0: renamed from veth5ca75b6
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.717129] br0: port 3(veth1) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.717134] br0: port 3(veth1) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.745070] eth1: renamed from vethb3fa547
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947599.7739] device (veth1bcd1b7): carrier: link connected
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.772881] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth1bcd1b7: link becomes ready
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.772974] docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth1bcd1b7) entered blocking state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm kernel: [ 3729.772977] docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth1bcd1b7) entered forwarding state
May 24 18:59:59 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm systemd[1]: docker-e72abc89230a93dbd8de3bda66bf8ad91795798da5bc3b403687855a60f52593.scope: Deactivated successfully.
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm dockerd[6782]: time="2023-05-24T19:00:00.047287409+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=e72abc89230a93dbd8de3bda66bf8ad91795798da5bc3b403687855a60f52593 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T19:00:00.047403871+02:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=e72abc89230a93dbd8de3bda66bf8ad91795798da5bc3b403687855a60f52593
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T19:00:00.047447705+02:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=e72abc89230a93dbd8de3bda66bf8ad91795798da5bc3b403687855a60f52593 namespace=moby
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T19:00:00.047464967+02:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm containerd[1211]: time="2023-05-24T19:00:00.053601909+02:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2023-05-24T19:00:00+02:00\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=11340 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.055925] br0: port 4(veth2) entered disabled state
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.055971] vethdb2d5b6: renamed from eth0
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947600.1017] manager: (vethdb2d5b6): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/100)
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.103787] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered disabled state
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.103964] veth4ca5297: renamed from eth1
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947600.1460] manager: (veth4ca5297): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/101)
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.146807] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered disabled state
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.147441] device vethdc001de left promiscuous mode
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.147443] docker_gwbridge: port 3(vethdc001de) entered disabled state
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm NetworkManager[1124]: <info>  [1684947600.1857] device (vethdc001de): released from master device docker_gwbridge
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: Removing a network device that was not added
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.213417] br0: port 4(veth2) entered disabled state
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.213686] device veth2 left promiscuous mode
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm kernel: [ 3730.213688] br0: port 4(veth2) entered disabled state
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm gnome-shell[2343]: message repeated 2 times: [ Removing a network device that was not added]
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm systemd[1]: run-docker-netns-b4a8d0809dc9.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 24 19:00:00 jobvm systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-c5223a1719d4dda5429fde03bd331827868f28a0fa686ad9e7520edd0bc6388e-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 24 19:00:01 jobvm avahi-daemon[1119]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth1bcd1b7.IPv6 with address fe80::2c90:faff:fecb:96ca.
May 24 19:00:01 jobvm avahi-daemon[1119]: New relevant interface veth1bcd1b7.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 24 19:00:01 jobvm avahi-daemon[1119]: Registering new address record for fe80::2c90:faff:fecb:96ca on veth1bcd1b7.*.
```

Comment: can yous share the system logs ?

Comment: you can have a look at my branch. I have implemented it for spring boot app with MySQL Db and both are using same network:
https://github.com/Maninder416/spring-boot/tree/spring-boot-mysql-docker-compose-both

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after adding a second interface to my server, and recreating the overlay network.
I had to:

- remove the node from docker swarm
- restart the docker daemon
- rerun docker swarm init

Restarting the daemon did the trick.